# Eclipse does not use my proxy settings when making API calls

Tags: eclipse, proxy

Using Eclipse Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)

Before I ask please be aware that I have spent 2 days trawling the web for an answer to this issue and found countless explanations on how to set proxy settings in Eclipse and have tried all of them but still do not get this working.

I have an automated test that makes a direct Oxiapi call (edited for security):

```
17/07/19 10:31:41 INFO http_helper.HttpHelper: Using URL: https://[hostserver]/oxiapi
17/07/19 10:31:41 INFO http_helper.HttpHelper: Request Body:
<oxip version="6.0">
    <request>
        <reqClientAuth returnToken="N">
            <user>[myuser]</user>
            <password>[mypassword]</password>
        </reqClientAuth>
        <reqAccountGetDetail>
            <userName>[username]</userName>
        </reqAccountGetDetail>
    </request>
</oxip>
```

When the call is made it times out with the following error:

```
17/07/19 10:32:02 INFO http_helper.HttpHelper: Could not connect properly. Check proxy information if needed.
```

All proxy settings are set both at a system level and in Eclipse. The tests are able to connect to the [hostserver] web pages which also require the same proxy.

If I make the same API call from postman then the I get a response.

Is there any setting in Eclipse that I am missing to allow these calls?

Comment: What are you setting in Eclipse so far?

Comment: I have tried setting my proxy to native and manual so far ensuring the proxy is set for everything but still no joy.  I have also tried adding proxy entries in the settings.xxml in.m for maven just in case that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested the issue I was having was resolved at the step definition level.  The API calls needed the proxy host and port added to them with in the test code as Eclipse does not use the proxy settings either from your PC or from Eclipse itself for API calls.